# Is there is any other method other than the cookie creation method to know whether file download is complete?

Tags: javascript, cookies, download

One way of checking whether the download is complete is by creating a cookie and  periodically checking for the existence of this cookie in the js file.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("fileDownload", "true");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
ServletActionContext.getResponse().addCookie(cookie);
```

But due to security reasons, we need to set this cookie to `cookie.setHttpOnly(true);`. 
So this cookie becomes non-accessible in the js file.

Is there any other way to solve this issue ?
Or is there any other way to check whether the file download is complete or not?

Comment: Since you're making a cookie whose sole purpose is to communicate with JS, and which contains no confidential data, you shouldn't use HTTPOnly.

Comment: *"Or is there is any other way to check whether the file download is completed or not?"* You can create another endpoint that calls to get a status update from the server.

Comment: Its resolved by this way. This can be done by calling json request in some interval of time and checking whether the download is completed or not. If download gets completed, a value can be set to request or session and this json request fired in regular intervals check whether that request or session value is available. If available json requests stops and mention as download complete. But this method reduces the performance